# Making NoData transparent in existing RGBA GeoTIFF

Tags: gdal, mapni

I have RGBA GeoTIFF where some areas have NoData values (255 255 255 255). Mapnik doesn't understand NoData and renders it as opaque white. How to make NoData areas as fully transparent?

I tried `gdalwarp -dstalpha in.tif out.tif` but it made NoData areas opaque black.